# Heroku local without ProcFile

Tags: go, heroku

Whenever I include a **Procfile** on a windows machine and I do `git push heroku master` it always fails to deploy. So I deleted all of **Procfile**, **Dockerfile**, **MakeFile** and **app.json** files and now when I did `git push heroku master` again it was successfully deployed without any issues.It's amazing.

Now I wish to `heroku local` to test locally and I am faced with the dreaded error message of `[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory`

Is there no way to run `heroku local` without the `Procfile`?

I am using Go with modules support.

Comment: So you deployed "successfully" without a Procfile but is your project executing properly on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, it is executing properly. All My Endpoints in the Web Dyno are up and running and receiving requests and sending back responses without any issue

Comment: According to the docs a `Procfile` is required to use `heroku local` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Comment: I strongly recommend fixing whatever problem you were having with your `Procfile`. What does "it always fails to deploy" mean, specifically?